# Draw 3D Cube knowing 3 points

Tags: tikz-3d

I need to draw this figure [image] and I only know the coordinates of points A(11,-1,2), B(13,2,8) and E(8,5,0).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please post a [minimal compilable document](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.

Answer (score 4):

You can use cross products to compute the other corners.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{110}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,line join = round, line cap = round,
    declare function={Ax=11;Ay=-1;Az=2;Bx=13;By=2;Bz=8;Ex=8;Ey=5;Ez=0;
        Fx=Ex+Bx-Ax;Fy=Ey+By-Ay;Fz=Ez+Bz-Az;}]
 \begin{scope}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\myn}{sqrt(pow(Bx-Ax,2)+pow(By-Ay,2)+pow(Bz-Az,2))}
   \def\tdplotcrossprod(#1,#2,#3)(#4,#5,#6){%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\tdplotresx}{(#2) * (#6) - (#3) * (#5)}% 
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\tdplotresy}{(#3) * (#4) - (#1) * (#6)}% 
        \pgfmathsetmacro {\tdplotresz }{(#1) * (#5) - (#2) * (#4)}}
   \tdplotcrossprod(Bx-Ax,By-Ay,Bz-Az)(Ex-Ax,Ey-Ay,Ez-Az)       
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\mynx}{\tdplotresx/\myn}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\myny}{\tdplotresy/\myn}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\mynz}{\tdplotresz/\myn}
   \path (Ax,Ay,Az) coordinate[label=left:{$A$}] (A) 
     (Bx,By,Bz) coordinate[label=above left:{$B$}] (B)
     (Ex,Ey,Ez) coordinate[label=right:{$E$}] (E) 
     (Fx,Fy,Fz) coordinate[label=right:{$F$}] (F)
     (Ax+\mynx,Ay+\myny,Az+\mynz) coordinate[label=left:{$D$}] (D) 
     (Bx+\mynx,By+\myny,Bz+\mynz) coordinate[label=left:{$C$}] (C)
     (Fx+\mynx,Fy+\myny,Fz+\mynz) coordinate[label=right:{$G$}] (G)
     (0,0,0) coordinate (O)
     (15,0,0) coordinate[label=left:{$x$}] (ex)
     (0,10,0) coordinate[label=right:{$y$}] (ey)
     (0,0,10) coordinate[label=right:{$z$}] (ez);
 \end{scope}    
 \draw[thick] (A) -- (B) -- (F) -- (E) -- cycle
  (A) -- (D) -- (C) -- (B) (C) -- (G) -- (F); 
 \begin{scope}
  \clip (A) --(D) -- (C) -- (G) -- (F) -- (E) -- cycle 
  (current bounding box.south west) -| (current bounding box.north east) -| cycle;
  \draw[very thick,-stealth] (O) -- (ex);
  \draw[very thick,thick,-stealth] (O) -- (ey);
  \draw[very thick,thick,-stealth] (O) -- (ez);
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}
  \clip (A) --(D) -- (C) -- (G) -- (F) -- (E) -- cycle ;
  \draw[dashed] (O) -- (ex);
  \draw[dashed] (O) -- (ey);
  \draw[dashed] (O) -- (ez);
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Merry Xmas!

Hidden lines hide, so in fact we can not see the hidden lines unless there is some transperancy. Dashed line are just a convention for expressing hidden lines. A dashed line is not real, and a hidden line is real, but hidden. Dashed lines are mostly used with black-white figures in the past. `Dashed` is not the only convention: think about hidden surface and dashed surface (what are they ? ^^). We may use colors, opacity/transparency, lightning as another ways of expressing hidden lines and hidden surfaces.

In Asymptote with module `three`, I just draw/fill things as they are, that is, ***easy***, ***relaxing for brain***, ***no tricky***. More precisely, I use `opacity(.5)` for filling faces of the cube. 3D effects are just great. You can see the labels `O` and `H` are transparent because they are hidden; the label `B` is normal, because `B` is visible. A usual built-in calculations are as follows.

- `cross(B-A,E-A)` is the vector of the cross product of vector AB and AE;
- `unit(u)` gives the unit vector in the direction of vector `u`;
- `a=length(B-A)` is the length of vector `AB`, i.e., the length of the side of the cube; therefore
- `D=A+a*unit(cross(B-A,E-A))` is the vertex D of the cube ABCD EFGH;

[image]

```
// http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
unitsize(5mm);
//import three;
import graph3;
currentprojection=obliqueX(55);
currentprojection.center=true;
//currentlight=nolight;  //  not working ? 
// vertexes of the cube
triple A=(11,-1,2), B=(13,2,8), E=(8,5,0), F=B+E-A;
real a=length(A-B);
triple D=A+a*unit(cross(B-A,E-A)), C=D+B-A;
triple G=C+F-B, H=G+E-F;
    
// pens for filling and drawing surfaces
pen pfill=green+opacity(.2);   // change opacity as you wish
pen pdraw=red+linewidth(1pt);
    
// define a command to fill and draw a face
void Drawface(triple A,triple B,triple C, triple D){
draw(surface(A--B--C--D--cycle),pfill);
draw(A--B--C--D--cycle,pdraw); 
}

// now come those faces
Drawface(B,C,G,F);Drawface(A,B,F,E);
Drawface(A,B,C,D);Drawface(E,F,G,H);
Drawface(A,D,H,E);
    
// labeling
dot("$A$",A,plain.SW);dot("$B$",B,plain.W);
dot("$C$",C,plain.NW);dot("$D$",D,plain.NW);
dot("$E$",E,plain.SE);dot("$F$",F,plain.E);
dot("$G$",G,plain.NE);dot("$H$",H,plain.NW);
dot("$O$",O,plain.NW);
    
// axes
//draw(Label("$x$",EndPoint),O--12X,Arrow3);
//draw(Label("$y$",EndPoint),O--10Y,Arrow3);
//draw(Label("$z$",EndPoint),O--8Z,Arrow3);
axes3("$x$","$y$","$z$",max=(10,8,8),Arrow3);
```