# How can I draw an area under a thermodynamic graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, arrows, arrows.meta,patterns.meta}

\tikzset{
    midar/.style 2 args={
        very thick,
        decoration={name=markings,
            mark=at position .55 with {\arrow{latex}},
            mark=at position 0 with {\fill circle (2pt);},
            mark=at position 1 with {\fill circle (2pt);}}
        ,postaction=decorate,
    },
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
        \draw[-{Latex}] (0,0) -- (0,5) node[above] {$P$};
        \draw[-{Latex}] (0,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {$V$};
        
        \draw[dashed] (0,4) node[left] {$P_{1}$} -| (1,0) node[below] {$V_{1}$};
        \draw[dashed] (0,1) node[left] {$P_{2}$} -| (4,0) node[below] {$V_{2}$};
        
        \draw (1,4) node[above left]{1};   
        \draw (4,1) node[above right]{2};  
        \draw[midar] (1,4) arc (180:270:3 and 3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

This is the picture that I get from the code:

[image]

This is an idea for what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Comment: In addition to providing us with code fragments in your question, consider also submitting the complete code that can be compiled to produce the shown output. The complete code is also called as Minimal Working Example (MWE). So we don't need to reassemble your code fragments.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Append the following code at the end of the `tikzpicture` environment

```
\fill[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=red] (4,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,4) arc (180:270:3 and 3) -- cycle;
```

Of course, you need to add `\usetikzlibrary{patterns}` in your preamble.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, It worked!

Answer (score 11):

Another possibility if you know the function of your plot you can use `fillbetween`:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,patterns}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel={V},
    ylabel={P},
    yticklabels={,,},
    ytick style={draw=none},
    xticklabels={,,},
    xtick style={draw=none},
    samples=200,
    axis lines=center,
    ymin=0,xmin=0,
    ymax=10,xmax=10,
    no marks,
    every axis x label/.style={
        at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},
        anchor=west,
    },
    every axis y label/.style={
        at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},
        anchor=south,
    },
    ]
    \addplot[blue,domain=2:4,name path=A] {15*e^(-0.4*x)+2}; %plot
    \addplot[blue,domain=2:3,-Stealth] {15*e^(-0.4*x)+2}; %arrow plot
    \addplot+[black,domain=2:4,name path=B] {0};     % dummy plot
    \addplot+[pattern=north east lines,pattern color=red!60!white] fill between[of=A and B,soft clip={domain=2:4}]; % fillingbetween A and B
    
    \addplot+[dashed,black,domain=0:2] {8.74};
    \addplot+[dashed,black,domain=0:4] {5.03};
    \addplot+[black,ycomb] coordinates {(2, 8.74)};
    \addplot+[black,ycomb] coordinates {(4, 5.03)};
    
    \coordinate (m1) at (axis cs:2,8.74); %mark1
    \coordinate (m2) at (axis cs:4,5.03); %mark2

       
  \end{axis}

    \filldraw[fill=blue,draw=blue] (m1) circle(0.05) node[above] {\small 1};
    \filldraw[fill=blue,draw=blue] (m2) circle(0.05) node[right] {\small 2};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Disclaimer: I only upvote correct answers accompanied with complete code.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:**
corrected function domain, added declared function `f(x)` and added missed elements of diagram.

A variation of  [@Roland answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595881/how-can-draw-an-area-under-a-thermodynamic-graph/595892#595892) with use of the `patterns.meta` library and a wee bit shorter code:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                decorations.markings,
                patterns.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
->-/.style = {decoration={%
    name=markings,
         mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{Stealth}}},
    postaction=decorate},
dot/.style = {circle, fill=blue, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=4pt,
              node contents={}},
                        ]
\begin{axis}[
declare function = {f(\x)=(12*e^(-1.4*\x)+1);},    
    axis lines=middle,
    xlabel=$V$, x label style={anchor=west},
    ylabel=$P$, y label style={anchor=south},
    xtick=\empty,
    ytick=\empty,
    xmin=0, xmax=5,
    ymin=0, ymax=5,
    clip=false,
    domain=1:4,
    every axis plot post/.append style={very thick, blue}
    ]
\addplot [name path=A] {f(x)}; %plot
\addplot [draw=none, name path=B] {0}; % x-domain
\addplot +[pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance={3pt}, line width=0.2pt]},
           pattern color=red] 
        fill between[of=A and B]; % patterns
\addplot [->-] {f(x)}; % for arrow on the middle of curve
%
\draw[densely dashed] (0,{f(1)}) node[left] {$P_1$} 
        -| (1,0) node[below] {$V_1$}    node[pos=0.5,dot,dot,label=1];
\draw[densely dashed] (0,{f(4)}) node[left] {$P_2$} 
        -| (4,0) node[below] {$V_2$}    node[pos=0.5,dot,dot,label=2];
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Disclaimer: I only upvote correct answers accompanied with complete code.

Comment: @Kim : Good to know! ;-)

Comment: @AlexG: Double upvotes for answers with `animate`. :-)

Comment: @Kim : I knew you would have multiple accounts :-D

Comment: @AlexG: Considering your expertise,  I believe you can create a special PSTricks package for drawing stereometry as what I asked in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/549836/which-latex-packages-do-really-support-3d-points-manipulations-etc). :-)

Comment: @Kim : Oh my, you are by far overrating my skills... The mostly french-speaking PSTricks Guru(s) publish elsewhere: http://pstricks.blogspot.com

Comment: @AlexG: No. I am not overrating but telling a truth. I know that site, but I cannot understand his explanation in French.